# How can I generate a 1 Hz clock from 100 MHz clock using VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, frequency, counter, vlsi

How can I generate a 1 Hz clock from 100 MHz clock using VHDL?

```
LIBRARY IEEE;    
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;    

entity digi_clk is
    port (
        clk1 : in std_logic;
        clk : out std_logic
    );
end digi_clk;

architecture Behavioral of digi_clk is
    signal count : integer :=0;
    signal b : std_logic :='0';
begin
    --clk generation.For 100 MHz clock this generates 1 Hz clock.    
    process(clk1)     
    begin
        if(rising_edge(clk1)) then
            count <=count+1;
            if(count = 49999999) then
                b <= not b;
                count <=0;
            end if;
        end if;
        clk<=b;
    end process;
end;
```

This is the code I got but I am not able to understand why they have used (count = 49999999) instead of (count = 50000000).

Comment: You've mixed up Verilog with VHDL, it seems, Gaurav, as user_... correctly noticed. You should very likely review your learning material twice.

Comment: Understand this Q&A. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that value written to a register does not update (i.e. appear when read) until the NEXT clock cycle after the register is written to.

So if I write a value to a register on *this* clock cycle, I won't read that value from the register until the *next* clock cycle.

So if I want things a register to read a particular value on the nth clock cycle, I have to write it on the (n-1)th clock cycle.

This isn't software. Signals in Verilog and VHDL do not update instantly like variables in software.

Answer (score 0):

The value of 0 will exist in your count signal for an entire clock cycle.

So if each value takes 1 clock cycle in the sequence: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

That's 5 clock cycles total.